# Convert Mac filename

Tags: .net, macos, filenames

I have received a file from a Mac and want to convert it to a proper Windows filename using c# or vb.net.

This is the filename: `SXXXX-NN-AA-02301-C-Typenu╠êbersicht 2020.dwg.`

This is what it should be: `SXXXX-NN-AA-02301-C-Typenübersicht 2020.dwg.`

How do I convert this properly?

Comment: Related? [Different utf8 encoding in filenames os x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6153345/1364007)

Answer (score 0):

This is a UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion issue. The "╠ê" is the escaped "ü", but Windows isn't picking up the escaping.

Something like:

```
     bUTF8 = GetRawBytes(fileNameGoesHere);
  bUnicode = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, bUTF8);
  strUnicode = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bUnicode);
```

should work. You might need to play with Encoding.UTF8/Encoding.UTF16 parameters.

Comment: I can't convert the filename to a byte array since the ASCII value of the ╠ character is 9568.