# mkdir with some emoji returns error: illegal byte sequence

Tags: shell, unicode, emoji, mkdir, macos-big-sur

I tried to execute `mkdir` with emojis to create directories.

```
mkdir
```

succeeded, but

```
mkdir
```

failed with error message `Illegal byte sequence`.

Is there anyway to successfully create the directory with the later emoji?

(macOS Big Sur 11.7.2, zsh)

Comment: FWIW, I don't get that error on Linux with Bash. I understand filenames can contain literally anything except the null byte.

Comment: How do you enter the emoji? If you pipe to hexdump (`printf  | hexdump`), what do you get? For me, it's `f09faba2`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. 0000000 f0 9f ab a2
0000004

Comment: FWIK, you can't freely use UTF8 in file names on the Mac. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153345/different-utf8-encoding-in-filenames-os-x).

Comment: Perhaps I need to correct myself: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), this may be possible depending on the file system you are using, but that Wiki site also lists certain limitations, when you want to do this on the command line.